# Mysql TRIGGER not taking function returned value on update

Tags: mysql, triggers, subquery

I have this Query which tries to update several values in another table after a insertion has been commited. Inside the trigger there is a function called `calc_distance` which returns a **DOUBLE** type value.

So, the problem is that no matter if I call the function properly the update is not taking the returned value. I tested the function running it separately from the mysql command prompt and in fact it returned the expected calculation.

So can someone please tell me what's going on on this query?

```
    DELIMITER ;;
    TRIGGER `DB1`.`update_coords`
    AFTER INSERT ON `DB1`.`TABLE_tracking`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    DECLARE LAT1, LAT2, LNG1, LNG2, DISTANCE DOUBLE;
    UPDATE TABLE_vehiculos SET ultima_comunicacion = now(),
    googlelat=(IF(NEW.latitude<>0,NEW.latitude,googlelat)), googlelong=(IF(NEW.longitude<>0,NEW.longitude,googlelong)),
    tipo_data=NEW.command, reported_command=(IF(NEW.valid=1,"F","A")), velocidad=NEW.speed, status="A",

    /* HERE COMES THE FUNCTION THAT IS NOT DOING ANYTHING */
    odometro=odometro+calc_distance(googlelat,NEW.latitude,googlelong,NEW.lontitude)
    /* --------------------------------------------------- */

    WHERE imei = NEW.device_id;
    END ;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

I declared `LAT1`, `LAT2`, `LNG1`, `LNG2`, `DISTANCE` to set all those variables with NEW.latitude and so on, but I realized that I cannot do anything with those variables because I cannot access NEW.latitude and the values `googlelat` or `googlelong` until I call update `tableX`, so, what is going on?
I tested the `calc_distance` function like this:

```
    mysql> select calc_distance(9.104550000000, 9.102577000000, -79.370780000000, -79.3622423000000);
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | calc_distance(9.104550000000, 9.102577000000, -79.370780000000, -79.3622423000000) |
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |                                                                 0.9627214584265752 |
    +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please I've been hitting my head against the monitor for the last 6 hours, please help!!

```
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE FUNCTION `calc_distance`(`lat1` DOUBLE, lat2 DOUBLE, lng1 DOUBLE, lng2 DOUBLE)
    RETURNS DOUBLE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE radio INTEGER(5);
        DECLARE distance DOUBLE;
        set radio = 6371;
            SELECT radio * 2 * ASIN
            ( SQRT (POWER(SIN((lat1 - lat2)*pi()/180 / 2),2) +
            COS(lat1 * pi()/180) * COS(lat2 *pi()/180) *
            POWER(SIN((lng1 - lng2) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) ) into distance;
        RETURN distance;
    END ;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with this function, and not with the surrounding query? Your updating one column (eg. googlelat) and then reading its value later on inside the same statement looks fishy to me.

Comment: Well the trigger without the calc_distance call is running smoothly and is working perfectly... is updating all fields. now the calc_distance function is not working, the odometro field remains the same. When i say is not working, I'm refering to the fact that the update is not taking the result returned from the calc_distance function, in fact if you add odometro=odometro+googlelat+googlelong for example, it works... is the function calc_distance that is not working, however, if you call select calc_distance and give the required params, it returns the result without issues.

Comment: What I mean is: are you sure the function is receiving the expected values for its parameter `googlelat` abd `googlelong` ? Log their values from within your function.

Comment: I also checked if is receiving the params, very easily,. I did odometro=odometro+googlelat+googlelong+NEW.latitude+NEW.longitude and the result is in fact the sumatory of all involved fields, which means, is working...

Comment: check the function, I added it to this post at the end

Comment: COuld you redefine your function as not deterministic (`CREATE FUNCTION ... RETURNS DOUBLE NOT DETERMINISTIC ...`) and try again? This should not change anything, but it looks like we are not facing a normal behaviour here.

Comment: still the same result, the function is not updating the field.

Comment: how can I calculate and try to get the value using calc_distance(...) into varX and sum varX+odometro ??? is it possible?

Comment: Is this issues solved by any means ? I face the same issue @LuisParada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best solution, instead of trying to update from another table, why not update from the affected table directly?

```
    DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE TRIGGER `DB1`.`update_distances`
    BEFORE UPDATE ON `DB1`.`tb_vehiculos`
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    SET @DISTANCE = calc_distance(OLD.googlelat,NEW.googlelat,OLD.googlelong,NEW.googlelong);
    SET NEW.odometro = OLD.odometro + @DISTANCE;
    END ;;
    DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly try

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `DB1`.`update_coords`
AFTER INSERT ON `DB1`.`TABLE_tracking`
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE TABLE_vehiculos 
       SET ultima_comunicacion = NOW(),
           googlelat  = IF(NEW.latitude <> 0, NEW.latitude, googlelat), 
           googlelong = IF(NEW.longitude <> 0, NEW.longitude, googlelong),
           tipo_data  = NEW.command, 
           reported_command = IF(NEW.valid = 1, 'F', 'A'),
           velocidad  = NEW.speed, 
           status = 'A',
           odometro = odometro + 
                      calc_distance(IF(NEW.latitude <> 0, NEW.latitude, googlelat),
                                    NEW.latitude,
                                    IF(NEW.longitude <> 0, NEW.longitude, googlelong),
                                    NEW.lontitude)
     WHERE imei = NEW.device_id;
```

*FYI: Now it's a one-statement trigger so you don't need to change `DELIMITER` and use `BEGIN...END` block.*

Comment: Nop, is not updating the field odometro. Is still the same. sorry.

Comment: please see the update and check if the function is the problem.